# Problem streaming radio on Android 2.2 and up

Tags: java, android, streaming, media-player, internet-radio

I am currently designing an android application that incorporates radio streaming.  The app works as it should with devices below Android 2.2, but works slowly if the device is 2.2 or above. I am using the MediaPlayer object, and I am calling the 'setDataSource(mylink.com/radio.mp3)' method as well as the 'prepare()' method.  The problem seems to occur when the MediaPlayer is being prepared.  It just takes a very long time to ready itself for the play state.  And again, this issue doesn't arise on devices below Android 2.2.  Any ideas?

Comment: You could always take a look at the different versions of Android and see what they have done thati s different.

Comment: Are you comparing only different versions of Android or is it also different devices ?

Comment: Also, does it take longer on 2.2+ if you're using local files, or only while streaming?

Comment: I am comparing both versions and devices.  The problem occurs on all the devices (and emulators) of versions 2.2 and higher I have checked thus far excluding the galaxy tab, which was version 2.2.  Seems to run normally on that device.

Comment: As far as local versus streaming.  I can play a local file without delay but I can also play a stream that has finite length without delay.  I feel the problem occurs when I am streaming from a source without a specified length.  Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: I've also experienced this issue and agree that it has to do with the length.  Have you come across and solutions yet?

Comment: @javaTheHut any solutions you've run across?  We're hitting the same issue.